# jQuery Fancybox not loading external website content in iFrame

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I've been trying to link external Google Maps from [this website that I've developed](http://www.1coolearth.org/programs/native-planting/).

But Google Maps will simply not show up. I can't for the life of me figure out why, as content from the same server loads just fine.

You can see what I mean on the linked page: The form button opens up the form page in a fancybox, but the external site will not show up.

**Edit**: I just checked craigslist.org on the fancybox, and that works fine for me....why is Google Maps being difficult? I swear it worked about a week ago.

Comment: Did you notice the error `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options`?

Answer (score 1):

the used URL is incorrect, you use

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&t=h&msa=0&msid=212666641261148257994.00046cf6ecc5475a88857&source=embed&vpsrc=0&ll=35.320728,-120.748672&spn=0.308139,0.291824
```

try it with `output=embed` like this:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&amp;hl=en&amp;t=h&amp;msa=0&amp;msid=212666641261148257994.00046cf6ecc5475a88857&amp;source=embed&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;ll=35.320728,-120.748672&amp;spn=0.308139,0.291824&amp;output=embed
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a thread of how to open Google maps the easy way with Fancybox (v1.3.x).

You can find it [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/ef30ef118ec3ebb4/)